# Find a function $g$ such that $g$ is differentiable everywhere and $g'$ is not bounded as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Give an example of a function $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$
>   that is differentiable everywhere such that $g'$ is not bounded on the
>   interval $(−\delta, \delta)$ for any $\delta >0.$

The fact that  $g'$ is not bounded on the interval $(−\delta, \delta)$ for any $\delta >0$ suggests that $g$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ at $x=0$ so so far I've just been thinking of functions that satisfy this and then testing to see if they're differentiable everywhere. This is taking too long now, so I was wondering is there a way to actually use the fact that it differentiable everywhere to derive the function?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just construct such a derivative and then integrate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another option, which is more commonly used as an example of this exact phenomenon, namely a function that oscillates faster and faster as $x\to 0$, but is still squeezed thin ensure continuity and differentiability at $x=0$. For instance
$$
f(x)=\cases{0&if $x=0$\\x^2\sin(e^{1/x})&otherwise}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I can't immediately see why we need the $e$ in there (i.e what's wrong with $x^2sin(\frac1x)$ at $x\ne 0$?) Clearly this will make it oscillate faster as $x\rightarrow 0$ but I don't see why we need that. Thanks

Comment: For that matter I don't immediately see what's wrong with $xsin(\frac1x)$ either. But I haven't tested it yet. Thanks

Comment: @user307463 Assuming $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$, and $f(0) = 0$ (so the function is continuous), by definition $f'(0)$ is the limit of the quotient $(x\sin(1/x) - 0)/x = \sin(1/x)$ as $x \to 0$. But clearly this limit does not exist, so $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Your first suggestion $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable everywhere, but for $x \neq 0$, its derivative is $2x\sin(1/x)  - \cos(1/x)$, which remains bounded as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @user307463 So, in short, the $x^2$ is needed to make the derivative at $0$ defined, since the function is oscillating between positive and negative. The exponential is to make sure that the oscillations increase faster than the function itself is squeezed, so that the derivative really is unbounded. You don't _need_ exponential to do that. In fact, it's enough with $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$. I chose to use the exponential because I like it.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2\sin e^{1/x^2}          $$

Comment: How did you arrive at that?

Comment: That is not a function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Nex Okay, I should have added that the function equals zero at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^2 \sin (1/x^2)$ for $x\ne 0$, and $f(0)=0.$ Then $f(x)$ is (obviously) differentiable for $x\ne 0.$

For $x\ne 0$ we have  $|(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)|=|x\sin (1/x^2)|\leq |x|$ so $f'(0)=0.$

For $x\ne 0$ we have $f'(x)=2x\sin (1/x^2)-(2/x)\cos (1/x^2).$

For $n\in N$ and $x_n=\pm 1/\sqrt {\pi n}$ we have $|f'(x_n)|=2/|x_n|=2\sqrt {\pi n}.$